# Image Showing Through Hidden DIV?

Tags: image, html, hidden

I am currently working with a page that has a few hidden divs, being called on to be displayed later.

This is the code I have on the page itself causing the problem.

```
<div align="center" id="check">
Block of plain text right here.<br />
Checking...<br />
<img src="http://sw6.us/template/images/loading.gif" /><br />
<?php
require("databasetest.php");
?>
echo "check_data shown";
</div>
```

This code here is what I have modifying the "check" div on a style page

```
.check {
padding-top: 25px;
padding-left: 0px;
color: white;
align: center;
display:none;
}
```

As you can see the div is instructed to be hidden on page load via the style code. Everything is hidden except for the picture.

I don't believe the PHP is the issue because I included an echo displaying text which is properly hidden along with the HTML before it. I also took out that require command and the image was still not hidden. The image being a .GIF is not the issue either, I have tried using a .png and got the same problem!

Thanks for the help! It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is that .check or #check in css part, coz you are using id="check" in div

Comment: Maybe you should post your full code (or put it on jsfiddle.net) from what I can tell, it looks like there is an `echo` statement in the HTML code